# Python os.walk() method

Tags: python

I am new to stackoverflow. I have taken lot of help from this forum in writing the following code. The code below searches all directories/sub directories on the system drives but while looking into 'D' drive, it looks only those directories and sub directories that are after the folder in which i run this program.

I mean if I run this program from `D:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\myCode.py`, it will search directories and sub directories after `D:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\` not the entire 'D' drive. It works good with other drives while running from the same location. This is my code:

```
import os, string
total=0
for driveLetter in string.ascii_uppercase:
    try:
        if os.path.exists(driveLetter+':'):
            for root, dirs, docs in os.walk(top=driveLetter+':', topdown=True):            
                for name in docs:
                    try:
                        if (name.endswith(".docx")) or (name.endswith(".doc")):
                            print(os.path.join(root, name))
                            total+=1                          
                    except:
                        continue
    except:
        continue
print ('You have a total of ' + str(total) + ' word documents in your System')
```

Comment: What if you add a '\' after the 'd:' so you get 'd:\' I have a theory that without that it's referencing the cwd of the d drive which is where the program was launched from.  Not a windows guy so I could be totally off base (and my slashes could be wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows [each process may set a current working directory on each *drive* separately](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d). `D:` means the *current working directory* on drive D. Here the behaviour occurs, because on all other drives the current working directory is set to the root directory, but on `D:` it is the `D:\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\` because the working directory was changed to the location of the script. To refer to the *root* directory of `D:` unambiguously, you need to use `D:\`. Thus

```
drive_root = drive_letter + ':\\'  # double \\ because this is a Python string literal
if os.path.exists(drive_root):
    for root, dirs, docs in os.walk(drive_root, topdown=True):
```